# C# Join with OrderBy

Tags: c#

Here's an example of my code thus far.

```
@string.Join(", ", @piece.PieceThemes.Select(t => t.Theme.Title).ToArray())
```

I would like to order the array in descending order.  I found that .OrderByDescending() exists, but I'm having trouble understanding how to use it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What don't you understand about it? Can you [edit] your post with a [mre]?

Comment: First, don't try to put everything in a single line.  You're trying to find how `piece.PieceThemes.Select.....` work. How are you going to do that when the results aren't stored anywhere?  Second, don't put your code inside your Razor/MVC file. Pages and views are for displaying, not processing. Debugging views is a harder than debugging controller methods. In this case you don't even need to put that code in a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you provide a lamda function to specify the property to sort by

`@string.Join(", ", @piece.PieceThemes.Select(t => t.Theme.Title).OrderByDescending(x=> x).ToArray())`

in this case `x` is a string and you can just sort by it.